# Can I flag a chat message as redundant?

Tags: discussion, flags, chat, chat-flags

I've come across a chat message which, while not offensive in any way, is redundant, as there's a more complete chat message below it. Is it possible to flag it without summoning a SWAT team and getting the person who posted it banned for 15 minutes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why it would be relevant to get a chat message that is redundant removed. Generally that would mean that 99 percent of all chat messages could be flagged.

So the answer is no: you can't and shouldn't flag such messages. You could star the other message to make it stand out more.

Answer (score 5):

What for? Let it stay there. Like with questions and answers, there's no need to flag them if they are not really bad.

While flagging isn't a good option, you can ask a Room Owner to move the redundant message(s) to different room (e.g. Trash room) if others agree it clutters the room without real value.